# iOS6 UICollectionView and UIPageControl - How to get visible cell?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

While studying iOS6 new features I got a question about [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html).
I am currently testing it with Flow layout and the scroll direction set to horizontal, scrolling and paging enabled. I've set its size to exactly the same as my custom's cells, so it can show one at a time, and by scrollig it sideways, the user would see the other existing cells.

It works perfectly.

Now I want to add and [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to the collection view I made, so it can show up which cell is visible and how many cells are there.

Building up the page control was rather simple, frame and numberOfPages defined.

The problem I am having, as the question titles marks, is how to get which cell is currently visible in the collection view, so it can change the currentPage of the page control.

I've tried delegate methods, like cellForItemAtIndexPath, but it is made to load cells, not show them. didEndDisplayingCell triggers when a cell its not displayed anymore, the opposite event of what I need.

Its seems that -visibleCells and -indexPathsForVisibleItems, collection view methods, are the correct choice for me, but I bumped into another problem. When to trigger them?

Thanks in advance, hope I made myself clear enough so you guys can understand me!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You must setup yourself as `UIScrollViewDelegate` and implement the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`method like so:

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
}
```

**Swift**

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageWidth = self.collectionView.frame.size.width
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth)
}
```

Comment: Without having to create an IVAR for CollectionView:


`- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = _tutorialCollectionViewFrame.size.width;
    _pageControl.currentPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
}`

Comment: Yeah that is correct answer...:  func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageWidth: CGFloat = self.collectionView.frame.size.width
        self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth)
    }

Comment: I found it smoother to use scrollViewDidScroll instead because you could theoretically scroll side to side without the pageControl updating until it stops decelerating. My code looks like this:
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let page = Int(round(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.collectionView.frame.size.width))
        if self.pageControl.currentPage != page {
            self.pageControl.currentPage = page
        }
    }

Answer (score 18):

I struggled with this for a while as well, then I was advised to check out the parent classes of UICollectionView.  One of them happens to be [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and if you set yourself up as a [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html), you get access to very helpful methods such as **scrollViewDidEndDecelerating**, a great place to update the UIPageControl.

Comment: I added to my UIViewController the delegate but still the method is not being called. Any idea?

Comment: @Dejel Remember to set the delegate of the scrollview.

Answer (score 17):

I would recommend a little tuned calculation and handling as it will update page control immediately in any scroll position with better accuracy.

The solution below works with any scroll view or it subclass (UITableView UICollectionView and others)

in viewDidLoad method write this

```
scrollView.delegate = self
```

then use code for your language:

Swift 3

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) 
    {
       let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.width
       pageControl.currentPage = Int((scrollView.contentOffset.x + pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth)
    }
```

Swift 2:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) 
{
   let pageWidth = CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame)
   pageControl.currentPage = Int((scrollView.contentOffset.x + pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth)
}
```

Objective C

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = (self.collectionView.contentOffset.x + pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth;
}
```

Comment: Your calculations is better, but `-[scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:]` is better place for this code.

Comment: It's depends on your taste I think. Apple updates pageControl after scroll is finished, but for me updating of page control more often looks better for user. If it is not slow down performance you can use this method.

Comment: I saw not nice blinking while tapping on left and right parts of `UIPageControl` in this case. I mean change page by `UIPageControl` tapping.

Answer (score 8):

Another option with less code is to use visible item index path and set the page control.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self.pageControl.currentPage = [[[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] firstObject] row];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Place **PageControl** in your view or set by Code.
2. Set **UIScrollViewDelegate**
3. In **Collectionview**-> cellForItemAtIndexPath (Method) add the below
   code for calculate the Number of pages,

> int pages
>   =floor(ImageCollectionView.contentSize.width/ImageCollectionView.frame.size.width);
>       [pageControl setNumberOfPages:pages];

Add the **ScrollView Delegate** method,

## pragma mark - UIScrollVewDelegate for UIPageControl

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = ImageCollectionView.frame.size.width;
    float currentPage = ImageCollectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;

    if (0.0f != fmodf(currentPage, 1.0f))
    {
        pageControl.currentPage = currentPage + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        pageControl.currentPage = currentPage;
    }
    NSLog(@"finishPage: %ld", (long)pageControl.currentPage);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old one but I've just needed to implement this sort of feature again and have a bit to add which gives a more complete answer.

**Firstly:** Using `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` assumes that the user lifted their finger while dragging (more like a flick action) and therefore there is a deceleration phase. If the user drags without lifting the finger the `UIPageControl` will still indicate the old page from before the drag began. Instead using the `scrollViewDidScroll` callback means that the view is updated both after dragging and flicking and also during dragging and scrolling so it feels much more responsive and accurate for the user.

**Secondly:** Relying on the `pagewidth` for calculating the selected index assumes all the cells have the same width and that there is one cell per screen. taking advantage of the `indexPathForItemAtPoint` method on `UICollectionView` gives a more resilient result which will work for different layouts and cell sizes. The implementation below assumes the centre of the frame is the desired cell to be represented in the `pagecontrol`. Also if there are intercell spacings there will times during scrolling when the selectedIndex could be nil or optional so this needs to be checked and unwrapped before setting on the pageControl.

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
   let centrePoint =  CGPointMake(
    contentOffset.x + CGRectGetMidX(scrollView.frame),
    contentOffset.y + CGRectGetMidY(scrollView.frame)
   )
   if let index = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(centrePoint){
     self.pageControl.currentPage = index.row
   }
 }
```

One more thing - set the number of pages on the `UIPageControl` with something like this:

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 20
    return self.pageControl.numberOfPages
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple Swift

```
public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    pageControl.currentPage = (collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems().first?.row)!
}
```

*`UIScrollViewDelegate` is already implemented if you implement `UICollectionViewDelegate`*

Comment: I found that the accepted answer works better as it takes the row in middle of the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

If using `scrollViewDidScroll`, updating the page control should be done manually to ⚠️ **avoid the flickering dots** when you tap on the page control.

Setup the `UIPageControl`.

```
let pageControl = UIPageControl()
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = .label
pageControl.defersCurrentPageDisplay = true // Opt-out from automatic display
pageControl.numberOfPages = viewModel.items.count
pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pageControlValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

Implement the action (using the extensions below).

```
@objc func pageControlValueChanged(_ sender: UIPageControl) {
    collectionView.scroll(to: sender.currentPage)
}
```

Update `UIPageControl` manually on every scroll.

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
        
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        pageControl.currentPage = collectionView.currentPage
        pageControl.updateCurrentPageDisplay() // Display only here
    }
}
```

Convinient `UICollectionView` extensions.

```
extension CGRect {
    
    var middle: CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY)
    }
}

extension UICollectionView {
    
    var visibleArea: CGRect {
        CGRect(origin: contentOffset, size: bounds.size)
    }
    
    var currentPage: Int {
        indexPathForItem(at: visibleArea.middle)?.row ?? 0
    }
    
    func scroll(to page: Int) {
        scrollToItem(
            at: IndexPath(row: page, section: 0),
            at: .centeredHorizontally,
            animated: true
        )
    }
}
```