# Get indexPath of cell when it's being shown from collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I need to get an `indexPath` of the cell which will be shown (something like `viewWillAppear:` there is 1 or 2 cells shown at the time, paging is enabled).

I can't find any method/delegate which will tell me that cells were moved and `indexPath XYZ` will be shown now. Any help please?

edit: I have a `label` above `collectionView` where i want to display information about currently shown cell. The problem is I don't know where to send information from the cell to the label, that exactly this cell is now being displayed.

Comment: unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Don't you create those cells in the `UICollectionViewDataSource`?  Therefore you know the cell that's being created.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176333/ios6-uicollectionview-and-uipagecontrol-how-to-get-visible-cell

Comment: @NSS Yes, that's similar question. However method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` will not help, as it will update the label too late (we can see few other cells meantime, my label won't be updated). Other methods of `UIScrollView` also are not the best solution, as they update the information too often.

Comment: @trojanfoe I know which cell is being created, but i don't know which cell is being displayed. This is a different thing, as `UICollectionView` often deque a cell before displaying it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `cellForItemAtIndexPath` ... It will be called everytime a cell will be shown, even if it was shown before.

Did that answer your question? If not, please provide some code, cheers :)

Comment: I've shared code in my answer ;). `cellForItemAtIndexPath` be called, but nothing guarantees me that the visible cell will be the last one to be called - other cells may be called later and I'll override description for wrong cell. Thank you for your answer tho!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution (when using paging) was to use `collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` and this line inside:

```
NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath = [myCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems].firstObject;
```