# Create a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, autoresize

How do I create a horizontal paging setup that scrolls with autoresize?

Like this UI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZN66n01a1I

I can not figure out how to get everything to be universal.

Unfortunately, to test my layout per device, I have to move each grid layout into its only position before I run it.

So my overall question is, how do I create this layout that provides a clean working autoresize?

Comment: maybe you can use collectionView by coding

Comment: Do you want to only have 2 pages to scroll between (he has 4 pages) or do you want 2 images on each page?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog I want like a 2x2 or a 2x3 on each page...

So out of like 4 pages, I want to have a 2x3.

6 images on each page in a grid like fashion. But i still want to be able to have a pagecontrol setup.

BEST WAY TO THINK ABOUT IT: just like looking at your iphone screen but instead of 4 across, have 2 going across.

Comment: @aelam Similar layout to the default iPhone phone dial pad?

Comment: Just two pages to scroll across horizontally? if so, put your images into a collection view and add those collection views as the images in the array that populates the page control.  Is that the result you are looking for?

Comment: @msu_bulldog something like that.        But if still like to have it setup on a UIScrollView with page control. I'll try that tonight. Idk.

Comment: You can still have the UIScrollView with page control. For each page on the UIScrollView, set the image of that page as the container view.  Let me know if that works for you

Comment: This might help: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176333/ios6-uicollectionview-and-uipagecontrol-how-to-get-visible-cell

Comment: More help again? I have been able to get some of it functioning!